# Calculate percentage of up votes for each record.

Tags: php

I have searched this site and Google and I can't figure it out

```
<?php

$artistname = "SELECT * from voting";
$artistnameresults = mysql_query( $artistname )
or die( "Could not get video games " .mysql_error() );

for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_numrows( $artistnameresults ); $i++ ) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $artistnameresults );
    echo "<div>". $data['artist'] ." has " . $data['votes'] ." votes</div>\n";
}   


?>
```

How do I echo out percentage of total votes for each record from my table?

Comment: Would be useful if you told us anything about how the 'voting' table looks like.

Comment: it has name of artist and the number of votes each artist has

Comment: @user3397408 Could you edit your question and add an example row?

Comment: idnum 1 
artist daddy yankee
votes 6

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misunderstood the question earlier. To get the total number of votes, you could make another query, `SELECT SUM(votes) from voting` which would give you the number of total votes (and you save that somewhere). Then you do what @ailvenge wrote.

Answer (score 1):

So first I would get the total votes in the variable, then in the next for would check if the total votes is more than 0 to avoid the error.

```
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($artistnameresults);
$total_votes = 0;
$rows = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++ ) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array( $artistnameresults );
    $total_votes += $data['votes'];
    $row[] = $data;
}

foreach($rows as $data) {
    echo "<div>". $data['artist'] ." has " . $data['votes'] ." votes ";
    if($total_votes > 0)
        $temp_votes = $data['votes']/$total_votes;  
    else
        $temp_votes = 1;        
    echo '( '.($temp_votes*100).'%)';
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Comment: all of the percentages are coming out as 100%

Comment: <?php
 
 $artistname = "SELECT * from voting";
 


$artistnameresults = mysql_query( $artistname )
 or die( "Could not get video games " .mysql_error() );
 
 

for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_numrows( $artistnameresults ); $i++ ) {
 

 $data = mysql_fetch_array( $artistnameresults );
 echo "<div>". $data['artist'] ." has " . $data['votes'] ." votes ";
    if($total_votes > 0)
        $temp_votes = $data['votes']/$total_votes;  
    else
        $temp_votes = 1;        
    echo '( '.($temp_votes*100).'%)';
    echo "</div>\n";
}   
 
 
 ?>

Comment: You need 2 for loops. One for assigning the all votes to `$total_votes`. You omitted `$total_votes = 0` and the first for loop.

Comment: now i included both loops but all the percentages are coming out as 0%

Comment: this is how my output is coming out

Comment: Total number of votes is 22
has votes ( 0%)
has votes ( 0%)
has votes ( 0%)
has votes ( 0%)
has votes ( 0%)